# Grafana template issue

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, grafana-alerts

I am monitoring 30 servers with Grafana using Prometheus. But I use [template](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860) for this and I cannot use alert in the template. What would you recommend for this? The Monitor system does not work for me without the alert system. I would like to use one dashboard for all servers.

How do i convert variable ? Is there any example ?
`rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{instance="$node",job="$job"}[$__rate_interval])*8`

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question is how to create an alert rule for a query with variables. If so, then it is not possible at the moment. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6557) about it on GitHub, so the feature may appear at some point in future.

For now you can either create a dashboard/panel that do not use any variables, or you can setup [Alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) and define your [alert rules with prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/).

Answer (score 1):

As a rough workaround you can remove the templating altogether and put the alerts either together(single query) or seperately for each instance (multiple query)

```
rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{instance=~".*",job="<hardcoded_job_name>"}[$__rate_interval])*8
```

You would still see the the problematic instance in the mail/screenshot sent by Grafana.

This is a major drawback of Grafana and caused us to pickup other tools to fix the issue.

As mentioned by @anemyte, alerts with templates are currently not possible.